# Выбор все элементов массива в промежутке между элементами

Tags: python

Есть следующий массив:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

**Вопрос:**

Как вывести на экран элементы между `"2"` и `"5"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

print(myList[2:4])
['3', '4']
```